# Convert a DataSet with single column to multiple column dataset in scala

Tags: apache-spark, dataset

I have a dataset which is a DataSet of String and it has the data

```
12348,5,233,234559,4
12348,5,233,234559,4
12349,6,233,234560,5
12350,7,233,234561,6
```

I want to split this single row and convert this to multiple columns which says RegionId, PerilId, Date, EventId, ModelId. How do i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

you mean:

```
case class NewSet(RegionId: String, PerilId: String, Date: String, EventId: String, ModelId: String)
val newDataset = oldDataset.map(s:String => {
              val strings = s.split(",")
              NewSet(strings(0), strings(1), strings(2), string(3), strings(4)) })
```

Of course you should probably make the lambda function a little more robust...

Answer (score 0):

If you have the data you specified in an RDD, then converting that to dataframe is pretty easy.

```
 case class MyClass(RegionId: String, PerilId: String, Date: String,
 EventId: String, ModelId: String)

 val dataframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd,classOf[MyClass])
```

this dataframe will have all the columns with the column name corresponds to the variables of clas MyClass.